# ES6 why can I reassign a constant when defined in a loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am playing around with some pointless logic to better understand ES6 and have noticed a strange occurrence when defining a constant.

It seems possible to change a constant assignment when defined in a loop:

```
        "use strict";

        for(const i=0;i<10;i++){ //seting constant in loop
            console.log(i); //is reassigned and incremented 0,1,2,3...
        }


        const e = 0; //setting constant outside loop
        for(;e<10;e++){ //cannot reassign constant
            console.log(e);
        }
```

Is this expected behavior and can anyone shed some light on why this occurs, is declaration in the loop different?

[image]

---

Update from [Statements/const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

> This declaration creates a constant that can be global or local to the
>   function in which it is declared. Constants are block-scoped.

Comment: Wow, just tried this on Chrome Version 40.0.2214.94 and it generates an infinite loop, maybe because the constant is never muted. Which browser are you using?

Comment: That problably means chrome has it correct by not reassigning it(? but should probably throw an error) and still hoists the constant. In your case it seems like the `const` acts like `let` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#let_in_loops

Comment: In Firefox I get `TypeError: redeclaration of var i` for the first example

Comment: @BenjaminBlonde I am using canary v42, if you include `"use strict";` it will not create the infinite loop and will increment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<s>When you modify an "immutable binding", the [current draft](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-declarative-environment-records-setmutablebinding-n-v-s) only throws in the strict mode:</s>

As @kangax pointed out, reassignment of a constant should always throw, since `const` creates an "immutable binding" with the `strict` flag on ([here](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-blockdeclarationinstantiation)):

> If IsConstantDeclaration of d is true, then
>
> Call env’s CreateImmutableBinding concrete method passing dn and true as the arguments.

and [then](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-declarative-environment-records-setmutablebinding-n-v-s):

> SetMutableBinding (N,V,S)
>   ...
>
> 5. Else if the binding for N in envRec is a mutable binding, change its bound value to V.
> 6. Else this must be an attempt to change the value of an immutable binding so **if S is true throw a TypeError exception.**

However, node only throws in strict mode:

```
"use strict";

const e = 0;
e = 42;  // SyntaxError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

(it's not clear why this is a "SyntaxError")...

In the non-strict mode, the assignment to the constant is silently ignored:

```
const e = 0;
e = 42;
console.log(e); // 0
```

Tested with node v0.10.35 with `--harmony` flag.

Comment: This looks like a bug in Node. Or it's not implemented. Reassignment to `const` should definitely throw, no matter the mode. If you look at https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-for-statement-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation you'll see that `const` results in `CreateImmutableBinding` with S=true, so it's a TypeError as soon as loop starts 2nd iteration.

Comment: You can also see exact support breakdown in our compat table — https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#const — which shows that "redefining a const is an error" is in fact missing in Chrome at the moment (which is what OP is experiencing, I'm guessing)

Comment: Can confirm this looks like a chrome specific issue, am not experiencing it in other browsers